# How to use SQLite installed by Homebrew rather than the default?

Tags: macos, sqlite, homebrew, version

`sqlite3 -version` yields:

> 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49 378230ae7f4b721c8b8d83c8ceb891449685cd23b1702a57841f1be40b5daapl

However, `brew upgrade sqlite3` yields:

> Warning: sqlite3 3.37.2 already installed

So there's a disconnect. However, I can access the brew sqlite3 using `/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3 -version` which yields:

> 3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5d17a0

Clearly I have the upgraded SQLite at that path. How do I set it to my system's default, so I can type `sqlite3` instead of `/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3`?

Comment: Like David said, update your PATH would be enough.

Answer (score 11):

Homebrew does not override SQLite because there is a macOS default SQLite overriding which may break the system.

To run the Homebrew version [invoke it explicitly](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Build-Software-Outside-Homebrew-with-Homebrew-keg-only-Dependencies#what-does-keg-only-mean):

```bash
$(brew --prefix)/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3
```

You can also [amend your `PATH`](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Build-Software-Outside-Homebrew-with-Homebrew-keg-only-Dependencies#path-modification) to make the change permanent. Running `brew upgrade sqlite3` only to check if a package is installed may unintentionally upgrade it. It is safer to simply `brew list sqlite`.